# pngcairo terminal not available in gnuplot 4.2

Tags: gnuplot

I currently have gnuplot 4.2 installed on my Oracle linux and it does not support pngcairo terminal.

`$ gnuplot --version
gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 6

> $ gnuplot --version

`gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 6`

My most of the gnu scripts are setting pngcairo as the terminal as its by far give the best outputs for graphs.

How can I get pngcairo to work ??

Or if I need to update the gnuplot ...what are the steps ..because I tried all update/check-update upgrade option of yum with no luck whatever so far..

Comment: You can set the terminal type to plain 'png', maybe the graphs won't be as pretty, but it should at least work.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but the lines were distorted a bit, is there no other workaround

Comment: You must update gnuplot, `pngcairo` was introduced with version 4.4

Comment: You could produce another format and use another program to convert to png (you can even add a system call to the end of your script to do this automatically).  If you produce svg (I am not certain off-hand if 4.2 supports svg) and then convert it, you will probably minimize any distortion or artifacts that a raster format may produce.